# Show that if $f'$ is greater than $0$, then $f(t_2) \geq f(t_1)$ if $t_1 < t_2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$f: [a,b] \to R, C^0$ on $[a,b]$, and Differentiable $(a,b)$

If $f'(x) \geq 0$ on $(a,b)$ then $f(t_2) \geq f(t_1)$ if $a \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq b$

I can clearly see that it is true. However, I'm honestly not sure how I would show this. All I know is that $f'(x) \geq 0$. I don't know anything about what $f(x)$ would send $t_2$ or $t_1$ to. So I'm not sure how to get the result from these assumptions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can prove this using either Rolle's Theorem or the Finite Increments Theorem (which is a generalisation of the former). Have you seen any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes,restrict the domain to $[t_{1} , t_{2}]$ then as $f$ is differentiable by Lagrange mean value theorem there exist $c\in (t_{1} ,t_{2})$ such that $f^{'}(c)=\frac{f(t_{2})-f(t_{1})}{t_{2}-t_{1}} \geq 0$ so $f(t_{2})\geq f(t_{1})$ as $t_{2}>t_{1}$.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I just did not see that. Thank you!